# How to hibernate in Debian Jessie

Tags: debian, hibernate

When I use the "hibernate" button in the Xfce menu on Debian Jessie (testing) The system seems to correctly hibernate and power off. Then when I power on again to resume it hangs before X is started (I can see the normal console boot message though).

So I wanted to install the `uswsusp` package, but it seems to be not available on Jessie.

Any ideas how I can enable hibernation on Jessie without `uswsusp`?

Answer (score 2):

This solved it for me. Apparently some BIOSes will not work with 'platform' which is the default.

```
# fix for current boot
echo shutdown > /sys/power/disk
```

To fix it across reboots:

```
# or fix permanently
apt-get install sysfsutils
echo "power/disk = shutdown" >> /etc/sysfs.d/local.conf
/etc/init.d/sysfs restart
```

Documentation:

- Old kernel documentation: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/power/basic-pm-debugging.txt
- My rough guide to install LMDE (Linux Mint Debian Edition) encrypted (LVM on LUKS): https://gist.github.com/seanorama/12c6383684022456a522

Comment: `/etc/init.d/sysfs restart` or `/etc/init.d/sysfsutils restart` (depending on your Debian?)

Answer (score 0):

Gnome users under Debian Jessie, need to install [https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/755/hibernate-status-button/] (Hibernate Status Button) extension.

Answer (score 0):

With systemd one should create `/etc/systemd/sleep.conf` with the following content:

```
[Sleep]
HibernateMode=shutdown
```