# How to debug Debian Jessie freezing on resume?

Tags: debian, freeze, hibernate

Every time I suspend my machine (at least the options say it is a suspend) the machine freezes within one minute of resuming. It seems to work fine for about a minute. After running for a bit, the mouse will move, but I can't click anything. After another short time, the mouse freezes as well, and I can't SSH in or toggle caps lock. If I hard reboot and read /var/log/kern/log, it has several lines about a hibernation error:

```
Mar 11 22:41:02 vera kernel: [ 1.367003] PM: Hibernation image partition 8:5 present
Mar 11 22:41:02 vera kernel: [ 1.367004] PM: Looking for hibernation image.
Mar 11 22:41:02 vera kernel: [ 1.367149] PM: Image not found (code -22)
Mar 11 22:41:02 vera kernel: [ 1.367151] PM: Hibernation image not present or could not be loaded.
```

I'm not sure exactly what logs to attach, but here is my /var/log/kern.log: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Cf3vudny

Any ideas on how to debug this? I've tried this solution, and it still freezes: [How to hibernate in Debian Jessie](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121869/how-to-hibernate-in-debian-jessie)

--EDIT--
I think it's a driver issue. I ran a Mint live disk, and it would suspend just fine. If I try to run

```
lspci
```

it also freezes like the suspend issue. I'm guessing drivers at this point, but it is hard to debug driver problems without lspci. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you manage this issue?

Answer (score 0):

That's not a hibernation error. That's printed when booting if you *didn't* hibernate. i.e. if you shutdown and boot up or reboot normally, that message is supposed to show up if hibernation support is enabled.