# lock screen session suspension in debian jessie

Tags: debian, suspend, freeze, hibernate, lock

[lock screen session suspension in debian jessie](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/314152/lock-screen-session-suspension-in-debian-jessie)

I just read of an issue that seemed similar to mine, and as I cannot comment yet and my problem is different I will ask my question outright. the similar issue can be found here: Suspend does not work on Debian Jessie

My 'particular' issue is that I seem to not only be unable to suspend but lock the screen or hibernate as I did in Wheezy. I find it odd that such a basic function doesn't work in a 'stable' release. Namely I use the lock screen frequently. When I couldn't, for the first time, I didn't. My system was unresponsive when I came back 30 minutes later. I ended up for restarting. On the upside, I am aware the 'much' of what was in the state it was can be directly recovered due to journaling.

Even so, there are things that are immediately obvious as not being how they were when I left. Frankly, I'm grateful that it's not more severe!

Still does anyone know the 'proper' way to report this bug? Also since my upgrade I don't yet have the anti-bug / bug tracking packages installed as of now. (My OWN fault, I know. If I did, I would be sending bug / craaash reports as I did in 'Wheezy'.)

also may be significant: KDE version changed to 4.14.2 (from 4.7.x I believe.) Dolphin also @ 4.14.2

I saw something similar here: [How to hibernate in Debian Jessie](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121869/how-to-hibernate-in-debian-jessie) but I really have no idea IF it aookies ti what I am working with. Thx in advance!

Comment: You didn't post the link to `Suspend does not work on Debian Jessie`.

Comment: hmmm. I never thought to use such a LOOONG tag :O. Clearly I am new, but that is QUITE descriptive :D. Thank you!

Comment: I tried. I do not have the rep to create new tags which is apparently what I must do. :(

Comment: No, to post a link highlight the text it should be covered by, press the link button and then paste the link. I mean the last sentence of the first paragraph.

Comment: OK, hope this edit will be what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `pm-utils` package for a bunch of power management commands. These are:

```
pm-hibernate       pm-powersave       pm-suspend-hybrid  
pm-is-supported    pm-suspend
```

As for the lock, there's the package `xscreensaver` in the repository. You might give it a try.

Comment: Honestly, I haven't played with the command line much. BUT, as I KNOW it is a hole in my knowledge, I will what you suggest a try :D

Comment: on pm-utils & pm-is-supported I am being told the command is not found by konsole.

Comment: You need to install the `pm-utils` package. Type this on the command line: `sudo apt-get install pm-utils`. And now press enter.

Comment: OK. Job done. Sorry I kind of gave up on it for a few days. Fortunately THIS is a home PC and not a work one. If this was @ work, this would be totally unacceptable. I WOULD have to log out and back on each time. I can't imagine running a server in this fashion!

Comment: OK, tried pm-suspend and have it working. I have no idea about xscreensaver though.

Comment: I'm really about ready to dump KDE over this issue.

Comment: Better check alternatives before and see if there's anything better.

Comment: I REALLY like KDE. I am seriously considering DOWNGRADING over this issue. I have thought about it and an older DE is still preferable to a different DE.

Comment: I in fact, DID stumble upon the solution. Nothing was working improperly. (excluding my reasoning, which was faulty.) It seems that my screen savers were improperly set up! :O

Comment: Good to know. Share the details as an answer. This might help other people.

Comment: I 'believe' what i did was do system settings>screen locker. Perhaps it became auto activated after I checked 'enable password'. Go figure huh? anyways, I set the screen saver to go up but for it to NOT require a password until a few seconds after that. That saves me having to type in the password while reading something lengthy.