# How to use uswsusp for standby/hibernation with systemd? (Debian)

Tags: debian, systemd, shutdown, hibernate

I use Debian Jessie and want to use uswsusp for stanby/Hibernation. Installing and configuring is no problem and it also works when you execute `s2disk` manually.
However with systemd the system seem to have changed drastically. Older explanations replacing pm-* files or similar do not work.
Also the [official wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/Hibernation#Suspend_and_hibernate_configuration_in_Debian_Jessie) does not help as the documentation there is way to less to be helpful.

[How to hibernate in Debian Jessie](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121869/how-to-hibernate-in-debian-jessie) is strongly related to this question, but there - however - only a fix is shown for the particular problem the user has without explaining how to use uswsusp.
However [in one answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121869/how-to-hibernate-in-debian-jessie#answer-274001) the [`sleep.conf`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-sleep.conf.html) is mentioned (I just doubt "shutdown" is the right entry to set there as we ... well... don't want to shutdown, but to hibernate).

So this file seems to be a good thing where you might change the hibernation system, but the man file is confusing and I don't get what I have to put in there.

**Extra:** Also explain how to use it first hybrid-sleep (or "Suspend Sedation" or how you'll call it) too.

Comment: I just installed it on my old notebook with ubuntu 16.04 (that has no replacement battery), I didnt even command it to suspend/hybernate... when I tried to boot it again (after shutdown), the only way I managed workaround the endless boot (that shows not log on pressing ESC) to be able to login was to: reboot in recovery; wait a huge lot until a message appeared, pressed ENTER and asked for a terminal, and `apt uswsusp remove`. :(, that problem didnt happen on my desktop ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 8):

In order to use `s2disk` with `systemd` in Debian, you must:

- Edit the hibernation service, with

  ```
  sudo systemctl edit systemd-hibernate.service
  ```
- Paste the following code

  ```
  [Service]
  ExecStart=
  ExecStartPre=-/bin/run-parts -v -a pre /usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep
  ExecStart=/usr/sbin/s2disk
  ExecStartPost=-/bin/run-parts -v --reverse -a post /usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep
  ```
- Update systemd

  ```
  $ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
  ```
- Nown run

  ```
  $ sudo systemctl hibernate
  ```

Comment: On some systems (Ubuntu 18.04 upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04, and maybe other distributions), the pre/post scripts are in ```/lib/systemd/system-sleep```, not ```/usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep```. Setting this path incorrectly in the hibernation service causes run-parts to fail silently.

Comment: One should also add ```-a hibernate``` after ```-a pre``` resp. ```-a post``` because some scripts check their second argument and behave differently eg. on suspend and hibernation.

Comment: @ysalmon you're so right! that path doesn't exist in my 18.04LTS.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to use your solution to run `pm-hibernate` command instead of `s2disk`, since that's the only one that successfully puts my machine into hibernation without blank screens etc. But it doesn't work. I just changed the `ExecStart=/usr/sbin/s2disk` line to `ExecStart=/usr/sbin/pm-hibernate`, but when I run `systemctl hibernate` I see a different behavior from just launching `pm-hibernate` from the terminal. Why does that happen?

Answer (score 0):

Read: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/power/basic-pm-debugging.txt

And: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-sleep.conf.html

So 'shutdown' is a good solution for desktops which don't have lids you can lift to trigger a resume. It basically means when the hibernate image is written to disk, shutdown.
Then when you hit power the kernel looks for a hibernate image and tries to use it.